# Calculating a percentage discount in SQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Basically just started using sql and having a minor problem. 
Working out the percentage of a number.

Example: What would I need to type in to work out:

2.75 - 5%

Drink_price= 2.75
After 5%discount = 2.61

So I need to deduct 5% of the price as a discount.

Sql doesn't seem to like the '%' key.

Comment: Have you checked the word "wildcard"? Should be 2.75 - 2.75 * 0.05 or similar.

Comment: Basic but legitimate question. I don't see any need to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really database administration. The way you do it cannot be done in most programming languages too. Calculate the discount as 95% of the drink price:

```
2.75*0.95
```

Comment: Oh okay i understand, I was thinking of calculations in the wrong sense. Awesome! Thank you very much and sorry for such a simple question. =)